# REST API with Django Admin

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am building an API-first app with the Django REST framework, so it has no html views at all and uses only token-based authentication. At the same time, I would like to make use of the Django admin interface, which is no problem, but I am worried about the performance costs as it depends on a lot of apps (sessions, standard auth, messages, csrf, etc.), that are not needed in the main app, but will run on every request.

Is there a way to set admin-specific middlewares to run only on the admin interface?

I know I can subclass them and raise MiddlewareNotUsed on all requests except ones going to the admin site, but maybe there is some build-in or well-known solution to this?

Comment: you're being paranoid for no reason. you're already building an API first app and the most you'll be doing on the Django Admin is probably debugging or just going over your DB. Don't worry about the performance. Don't overthink it.

Comment: @Sahil This is exactly the problem. no matter how I'm gonna use the admin, all the apps it depends on will run on every request, including requests from the api users

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, no, I don't think there are built-in solutions that cater to this. But that's probably because your purpose is not a good fit for Django's design and philosophy.

I'm with the comment by Sahil on this. I used to be paranoid about performance too, but I realized that I was underestimating Django's speed (even with all these basic middleware), and that if performance was *that* critical, I probably shouldn't be using Django in the first place. I'm guessing that disabling these middleware will save an app's response time only unnoticeable milliseconds at most; inevitable network fluctuations might even be more significant. A developer's time is more expensive than the additional hardware that could be thrown at any performance and/or scalability problems that come up.

But if you still want to save on the middleware processing, I have an alternative idea: the convenience functionality provided by the Django admin (that is, CRUD operations) could be replicated quite rapidly with DRF viewsets. Perhaps you could build a corresponding API client using some rapid-development frontend framework for your users. (I was going to say, just use the DRF browsable API, but I remembered that also relies on pretty much the same basic middleware as the Django admin.)